# How Can I Get SearchKit to Display Upcoming Events

Tags: civievent, searchkit, display

I want to display a list of upcoming events on our site.

Can I do that using searchkit? Whatever I attempt to do seems to fail - for the record - we have atleast 20 upcoming events.

If I remove the is current - I get all the events we ever had - but that is not what we are interested in displaying.

[image]

Comment: Is `"start date" > (date range) Today` not what you're looking for? Or does upcoming mean something different here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search you have created in the screenshot shows events which are running currently i.e event start date is <= today and event end date is null or >= today

To show upcoming event I would use start date >= now

[image]